# Is there a way to force all cs files to include a header comments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

We are using visual studio 2012. Ideally all csharp file (xxx.cs) should include a copy right comment in the header of the file like

```
#region Copyright GOOGLE 2013
// 
// All rights are reserved. Reproduction or transmission in whole or in part, in 
// any form or by any means, electronic, mechanical or otherwise, is prohibited 
// without the prior written consent of the copyright owner. 
// 
#endregion
```

My question is, if there is a way to automatically include that comment when we create the file? Or alternatively can use code-analysis to prevent non-comments cs file being checked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the templates Visual Studio uses when you create new files

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx

Your own custom templates could include the desired copyright notice.

Whether and how automated analysis at check-in can flag such files depends on the source code management system you are using.  Many provide pre- and post-checkin hooks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated an vs 2012 default class tempalte, for all new project, it works. But for existing projects, when I create a new c# file, the updated comments wont be there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you update an existing template or create a new one?  If you updated the existing one, I would think it would take right away in a current project.